# ¿Cómo hacer una media piramide inversa de * con un ciclo while de tamaño n?

Tags: python, while

Lo que tengo ahora es para formar una media piramide, pero la ocupo ahora invertida:

```py
limite = int(input("Ingrese un limite como valor entero: "))

i = 0
incremento = 1
simbolo = "*"

while i <= limite:
    print(simbolo * i) 
    #Funcion incremento/decremento
    i = i + incremento
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente cambia la impresiòn que realizas, actualmente esta aumentando:

```
print(simbolo * i)
```

Por ejemplo para un limite de `5` tienes una salida:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

puedes iniciar con el limite y decrementar su valor en cada ciclo:

```
print(simbolo * (limite - i))
```

para tener una salida:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

por lo tanto tu còdigo serìa :

```
limite = int(input("Ingrese un limite como valor entero: "))

i = 0
incremento = 1
simbolo = "*"

while i <= limite:
    print(simbolo * (limite - i)) 
    #Funcion incremento/decremento
    i = i + incremento
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar y por la ayuda. Y entiendo como decrementar el valor.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** No es necesario cambiar la condición de paro, tal como indica el compañero Jorge, con cambiar el método de impresión basta.

<s>Tienes que cambiar la lógica que tienes,</s> actualmente inicias en 0 y tu condición de incremento es que `i` se mantenga menor o igual a tu `limite`. Lo que tienes que hacer en su lugar es que mientras tu límite sea mayor a i puedes seguir iuncrementando, y al momento de imprimir al `limite` le restes lo que lleva `i`. Por ejemplo si tu `limite` es 3, entonces tienes:

1. `i = 0`; 3 - 0 = 3
2. `i = 1`; 3 - 1 = 2
3. `i = 2`; 3 - 2 = 1
4. `i = 3`; se incumple la condición ya que 3 no es mayor a 3 y se rompe el ciclo

```py
limite = int(input("Ingrese un limite como valor entero: "))
i = 0
simbolo = "*"

while limite > i:
    print(simbolo * (limite - i)) 
    #Funcion incremento/decremento
    i += 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar compañero. Se agradece.